# How i can add a node under a node using ObjectContentManager?

Tags: java, jackrabbit

I want to add a node under a node using ObjectContentManager.

I am able to add a single node using ObjectContentManager , using

```
Pojo1 p1 = new Pojo1 ();
p1 .setPath("/p1");
p1 .setName("p_3");
p1 .insert(p1);
ocm.save();
```

Now under this node I want to add another node of Pojo2 class.
I have written a code , but it is giving me exception.

```
Pojo2 p2 = new Pojo2 ();
p2.setPath("/p1/p2");
p2.setName("p_3");
p2.insert(p2);
ocm.save();
```

But this is giving me exception.

```
org.apache.jackrabbit.ocm.exception.ObjectContentManagerException: Cannot create new node of type nt:pojo1 from mapped class class com.sapient.Pojo1; nested exception is javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No child node definition for p2 found in node /p1
```

How i can achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As I read the [tutorial on ObjectContentManager](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/object-content-manager.html), you set up a mapping descriptor with XML or Java annotations in order to specify how your pojo is to be persisted.  Please add the mapping descriptor information to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the OCM test classes there's a good example of how this should be configured:
[A.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/commons/ocm/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/ocm/testmodel/A.java?view=markup)

```
@Node(jcrMixinTypes="mix:lockable" )
public class A
{
@Field(path=true) private String path;
@Field private String a1;
@Field private String a2;
@Bean(jcrType="nt:unstructured", jcrOnParentVersion="IGNORE") private B b;
```

The Bean Annotation is what's used to indicate that your persisting the object as another node rather than a property.

Here's the test code that adds the B object the A object [AnnotationBeanDescriptorTest.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/jackrabbit/commons/ocm/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/jackrabbit/ocm/manager/beanconverter/AnnotationBeanDescriptorTest.java?view=markup)

```
ObjectContentManager ocm = getObjectContentManager();
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create a main object (a) with a null attribute (A.b)
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
A a = new A();
a.setPath("/test");
a.setA1("a1");
ocm.insert(a);
ocm.save();

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Retrieve
// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
a = (A) ocm.getObject("/test");
assertNotNull("Object is null", a);
assertNull("attribute is not null", a.getB());

B b = new B();
b.setB1("b1");
b.setB2("b2");
a.setB(b);

ocm.update(a);
ocm.save();
```